# OpenGL ES Android Image Issue

Tags: android, opengl-es

I created a 2d game for Android with OpenGL ES.My images looks like in the picture below on some devices.What can be the problem?

Disorted image:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the good image for comparison?

Comment: @jenuine I'm using this framework :http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fch09-jumper%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fbadlogic%2Fandroidgames%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Comment: I'm just asking for ideas if someone encounter something like that before.It's not possible to put all the code here.

Comment: What is the bitmap format you're using? And what internal (gl) texture format?

Comment: @Aert I'm using RGB565 bitmap format because RGB8888 cause some fps problems.I don't have an internal bitmap format.I'm using GLUtils.texImage2D like that:GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

Comment: So I've had this happen when there was a mismatch between the GL and bitmap format, but i did my own bitmap loading and used glTexImage2D. Also that it only happens on some devices doesn't align with that theory...